# sql select row based on column is null or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample data

```
ID    SettingID   DifferentSettingID  Value
1     100         Null                True
2     100         5                   False
3     101         Null                0
4     101         5                   1
5     102         NULL                100
```

Wanted results

```
ID    SettingID   DifferentSettingID  Value
2     100         5                   False
4     101         5                   1
5     102         NULL                100
```

Where the SettingID needs to be unique

Comment: What did you try first of all?

Comment: I assume you prefer the row where DifferentSettingID is not NULL and if not available take the row with DifferentSettingID = NULL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `row_number` window function:

```
;with cte as(select *, row_number() 
                         over(partition by SettingID order by ID desc) rn from TableName)
select * from cte 
where rn = 1
```

This window function will number rows in partitions by `SettingID` value. For example for `SettingID = 100` it will give number `1` to `ID 2` and number `2` to `ID 1`(because of `desc ordering`). Same for `SettingID = 101`... So each partition(value of `SettingID`) will get `row_number=1` for biggest `ID` in that partition. The rest is just filtering by `rn=1`.

Comment: Not sure why somebody downvoted this. This is the best way to do this.

Comment: I do think some explanation would be nice.

Comment: i would want to prefer the rows with a DifferentSettingID  = 5 these may not be in order

Comment: @theHaggis, then instead of `order by ID desc` do `order by DifferentSettingID desc`